# Test if each line in a file contains one of multiple strings in another file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a text file (we'll call it `keywords.txt`) that contains a number of strings that are separated by newlines (though this isn't set in stone; I can separate them with spaces, commas or whatever is most appropriate). I also have a number of other text files (which I will collectively call `input.txt`).

What I want to do is iterate through each line in `input.txt` and test whether that line contains one of the keywords. After that, depending on what input file I'm working on at the time, I would need to either copy matching lines in `input.txt` into `output.txt` and ignore non-matching lines or copy non-matching lines and ignore matching.

I searched for a solution but, though I found ways to do parts of what I'm trying to do, I haven't found a way to do everything I'm asking for here. While I could try and combine the various solutions I found, my main concern is that I would end up wondering if what I coded would be the best way of doing this.

This is a snippet of what I currently have in `keywords.txt`:

```
google
adword
chromebook.com
cobrasearch.com
feedburner.com
doubleclick
foofle.com
froogle.com
gmail
keyhole.com
madewithcode.com
```

Here is an example of what can be found in one of my `input.txt` files:

```
&expandable_ad_
&forceadv=
&gerf=*&guro=
&gIncludeExternalAds=
&googleadword=
&img2_adv=
&jumpstartadformat=
&largead=
&maxads=
&pltype=adhost^
```

In this snippet, `&googleadword=` is the only line that would match the filter and there are scenarios in my case where `output.txt` will either have only the matching line inserted or every line that doesn't match the keywords.

Comment: Isn't that just `grep -Ff`?

Comment: Take a look at `man grep`.

Comment: `grep -Ff` looks like it would work. I'll give it a try and see what happens. Looks like I can use `grep -Ffv` for the cases where I want to copy non-matches.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: `I searched for a solution but, though I found ways to do parts of what I'm trying to do, I haven't found a way to do everything I'm asking for here. While I could try and combine the various solutions I found, my main concern is that I would end up wondering if what I coded would be the best way of doing this.` And indeed, the suggestion so far to use Grep is infinitely simpler than combining the solutions I found (e.g. before asking this question, I was considering assigning the contents of `keywords.txt` to an array). Also, that question's best answer is dripping with sarcasm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Assuming the content of `keywords.txt` is separated by newlines:**

```
google
adword
chromebook.com
...
```

The following will work:

```
# Use keywords.txt as your pattern & copy matching lines in input.txt to output.txt
grep -Ff keywords.txt input.txt > output.txt

# Use keywords.txt as your pattern & copy non-matching lines in input.txt to output.txt
grep -vFf keywords.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

---

**2. Assuming the content of `keywords.txt` is separated by vertical bars:**

```
google|adword|chromebook.com|...
```

The following will work:

```
# Use keywords.txt as your pattern & copy matching lines in input.txt to output.txt
grep -Ef keywords.txt input.txt > output.txt

# Use keywords.txt as your pattern & copy non-matching lines in input.txt to output.txt
grep -vEf keywords.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

---

**3. Assuming the content of `keywords.txt` is separated by commas:**

```
google,adword,chromebook.com,...
```

There are many ways of achieving the same, but a simple way would be to use `tr` to replace all commas with vertical bars and then interpret the pattern with grep's extended regular expression.

```
# Use keywords.txt as your pattern & copy matching lines in input.txt to output.txt
grep -E $(tr ',' '|' < keywords.txt) input.txt > output.txt

# Use keywords.txt as your pattern & copy non-matching lines in input.txt to output.txt
grep -vE $(tr ',' '|' < keywords.txt) input.txt > output.txt
```

---

> **Grep Options**
>
> ```
>  -v, --invert-match
>        Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.   
>
>  -F, --fixed-strings
>        Interpret each data-matching pattern as a list of fixed strings, 
>        separated by newlines, instead of as a regular expression.
>
>  -E, --extended-regexp
>        Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression
>        (i.e. force grep to behave as egrep).
>
>  -f file, --file=file
>        Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.
>        Empty pattern lines match every input line.
>        Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.
>        If file is empty, nothing is matched.
> ```
>
> Read more about [grep](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep)
>
> Read more about [tr](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tr)

Comment: `I searched for a solution but, though I found ways to do parts of what I'm trying to do, I haven't found a way to do everything I'm asking for here. While I could try and combine the various solutions I found, my main concern is that I would end up wondering if what I coded would be the best way of doing this.` And indeed, the suggestion so far to use Grep is infinitely simpler than combining the solutions I found (e.g. before asking this question, one solution I was considering suggested assigning the contents of `keywords.txt` to an array).

Comment: Also, if you don't want to answer these sort of questions, that is your choice and you are entitled to it but don't tell other contributors that they aren't entitled to making that same choice in a manner that doesn't align with yours. Also, are you the one that downvoted Tobiasbueschel's answer? If so, that means you are abusing the rating system by rating answers for political/opinionated reasons rather than based on how well it answers the question.

Comment: Finally managed to test your answer and it was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!